# Users info are re-initialized after logging out and signing in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Whenever the user is logging out and tries to log in once more all the attributes in the `JSON` tree are re-initialized.

Here's my code:

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    FirebaseUserMetadata metadata =mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();
                    if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
                        // The user is new, show them a fancy intro screen!
                        User user = new User(firebaseUser.getUid(), firebaseUser.getDisplayName(), firebaseUser.getEmail());

                       mDatabaseReference.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
                    } else {
                        // This is an existing user, show them a welcome back screen.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
```

I tried to use user's metadata but even that didn't work.

Here is my `JSON` structure

[image]

Comment: What do you do when you are logging out?

Comment: After logging out nothing changes in the database, the problem arises whenever I re-login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to check if a user is new, it's the same thing if we check if the user logs in for the first time. So to solve this, we can simply call the `isNewUser()` method in the `OnCompleteListener.onComplete` callback like this:

```
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> completeListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
            if (isNewUser) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Is New User!");
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Is Old User!");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For more informations, please see the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo).