# Write unique android device ID to firebase firestore on first login

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've googled this for hours but can't seem to find an answer.

I want to grab the unique device ID upon first login and store it in the users firestore document so that I can identify each device associated with that users account, I'm already using the onCreate firebase cloud function to generate fields upon first login but cannot figure out how to get the device to store its ID there.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can get the device id using the following line of code:

```
String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

So beside the other user informations that you have, now you can also store the device id.

Comment: What would be the best way to store this upon first run? Is there a way for a cloud function to call a function from the android device or should the android device call the cloud function? I want this to persist on app updates and uninstalls occurring.

Comment: When the user signs up there is a workarung that can help you know if the user is new. For that, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568880/users-info-are-re-initialized-after-logging-out-and-signing-in/49587394)**. So if the user is new, just add the device id to the user object. This is client side. You cannot also create a function but I don't see how it will help you in this case.

Comment: I'm guessing that this wouldn't work with each device signing in for the first time though? Basically I want the user to be able to create an account but then each device that user connects with gets it's ANDROID_ID stored so that I can monitor what each device is doing.

Comment: In this case, you need to check everytime the user logs in, to see if the he users the same device or not. If the user is using another device, then you should create a map, and store every device. A single property won't help you in this case, right?

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: @Alex Mamo on reinstalling app will it give same I'd or different?

Comment: @RealTechHacks It will be the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

you can get Unique Device ID from System using ,

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

you also have to add, following permission in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Comment: `getDeviceId` is deprecated method. Also I'm not sure if it is valid for tablet devices. It's better to use `ANDROID_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the currently best choice would be [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

For other solutions check this blog post : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html